# IE11 fullscreen doesn't work properly in Iframe

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I was trying to implement fullscreen in IE11 using bigscreen.js. It works well with some hack.
    But It doesn't work well with the same url embedded in IFrame.
I have video and canvas element in IFrame. Video element successfully goes to fullscreen.
But canvas, svg and some other elements are not going to fullscreen mode.
    Is this the known issue with IE11? If so is there any around to make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet? I’m particularly interested in seeing the iframe markup that’s being used to embed the video, canvas, SVG, etc.

Disclosure: I am on the team that worked on Microsoft's implementation of the Fullscreen API.

Comment: Please check this out. http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/814527/ie11-iframes-body-offsetwidth-incorrect-when-iframe-is-in-full-screen-mode

Answer (score 0):

You have to click F12 (open developer tools)
Try all combinations to IE Mode ans Quirks Mode
You will find one that works (if you come from IE10) probabely :
Navigator Mode IE10 / Quirks Norme